# Webpack dev server DO reload, but page not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "postronix",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "transpile": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.15.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
                'plugins': ['react-html-attrs']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('public/style.css', {
        allChunks: true
    })
    ]
}
```

i run this command:

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base ./ --hot
```

whenever i make changes to my app.js file, this log shown in gitbash:

```
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 183ms
           Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   app.bundle.js    532 kB       0  [emitted]  main
public/style.css  84 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} app.bundle.js, public/style.css (main) 496 kB [rendered]
    [0] ./src/app.js 1.1 kB {0} [built]
     + 300 hidden modules
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

in chrome web browser, i opened http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/, the page screen DO reload every i modify app.js, but no any change to the page, it's like the app.js just the same as before i make change.

its just compiled only with webpack --watch.

please help

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer.
i put publicPath: "/assets/" in webpack.config.js

and in index.html i add "assets" path for referring script:

```
<script src="assets/app.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/public/style.css">
```

now, its compile and reload perfectly.